# Raster tool *Extract by Attributes* creates odd output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcmap, spatial-analyst, extract

**BACKGROUND:**

At 10.8.1, I have a raster tif that contains the following statistics.  Please note the maximum value:

[image]

I want to create an output raster containing those cells whose values are greater than or equal to zero.  I use the Spatial Analyst tool, *Extract by Attributes* as shown here:

[image]

The tool runs without error.  However, the output tif's maximum value is now different than the input tif:

[image]

This difference in maximum value is also confirmed with the *Get Raster Properties* tool.

**QUESTION:**

I expect the output raster's maximum value to be the same as the input raster.

Why are they different?

Comment: What you see in that source tab might be an estimation, run your raster through the build statistics tool first.

Comment: Hey, that worked!  Post it as an answer and I'll credit you.  BTW, how can I tell if the Build Statistics tool has been previously applied to a raster?

Comment: You can't to my knowledge but I may be wrong? It does not affect processing such the extract tool you used, just the visualisation of it if you are using a stretch.